# Append Query based on Matching a single field

Tags: mysql

Super new to using mysql, so try to keep answers simple. Here is the scenario: I am connected to MySQL Server through Toad for MySQL. I have two tables, one with one column titled 'email address' that has 8 records, and the other table has 20+  columns with over 1 million full records: first name, last name, email, state, etc. (full records). Originally I was using MS Access and using the append query there. Here is what I need: We will call the two tables 'Email Address' (only one column) and 'Full records' (20+ columns). What I want to do is append data from table 'Full records' to the table 'Email Address' based on a matching what is in the single column in 'Email Address' to the 'Full records'. I want all columns where a match=true to then be appended to the 'email address' table. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL INNER JOIN clause compares it with each row of the T2 table to check if both of them satisfy the join condition. When the join condition is matched, it will return the row that combine columns in both T1 and T2 tables.
For more info please refer this [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx).

`select
    Other_Table.Name,
    .... //u can select any column which u want from both tables
    ....
    Email_Address.emailId
FROM
    Other_Table
join                // (inner) join 2 table; this is always match true condition
     Email_Address
ON
    Email_Address.emailId=Other_Table.email //conditional column values.`